# Mechanical Turk: Using "input" CSVs with Boto

Tags: boto, mechanicalturk

In the Mechanical Turk Command Line Tools [`external_hit` example](http://web.mit.edu/cathywu/Public/AMT/aws-mturk-clt-1.3.0/UserGuide.html#externalhit), a CSV titled `external_hit.input` is uploaded along with `external_hit.question` and `external_hit.properties`. This CSV contains values that will be injected into the `ExternalURL` element in `external_hit.questions`.

I would like to use `boto.mturk` to construct the same example. How do I upload `external_hit.input` when creating a new HIT with `boto`?

Comment: Might I suggest https://github.com/ctrlcctrlv/mturk-python in lieu of Boto? Also, the CLT is not the same as the API. You're going to need to use Python's `csv` module with either library.